# The system is running in low-graphics mode ubuntu 14.04 after samba

Tags: 14.04, graphics, recovery-mode

recently I tried to install samba in my ubuntu 14.04 after installation pc asked me to restart.

after Restarting I'm getting an error "**The system is running in low graphics mode**" I tried all the troubleshooting but none of them helped me.

I was running ubuntu on a basic PC I don't know anything about its graphic or graphics card.

More over I'm not able to connect to internet as there is a fire wall,until I login to it, It will not give me internet. 
I tried to connect use internet from cellphone but it also not working.
In addition I can't login to the recovery mode to by holding "**shift**"

Please suggest me an offline way if there OR suggest me how to do online in keeping in mind my internet situation.

I also seen this [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

Comment: Did you tried with a more recent version?

Comment: @SiGe Ubuntu 14.04 LTS has nearly 2 years of official support.  It would be better for a user to try to resolve an issue with a supported version of Ubuntu before quickly starting over with a fresh install.  Not trying to resolve an issue can leave the user somewhat vulnerable to the same thing happening when configuring or using a fresh install.

Comment: What is the output of `egrep greeter-setup-script /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf`

Comment: No output.. @L.D.James

Comment: In trying to compose a resolution for you, I'm studying to access what has been done and what is left to do.  I believe your first and most important step toward resolving your issue would be to fix your Internet connectivity problem.   It might not be easy for the Ubuntu update system to provide you with the correct graphic drivers without being able to update the repositories and download/install the drivers.  Can you specify how you installed **Samba** without Internet access?  I will include the same method for installing the graphic drivers in the answer I'm composing.

Comment: While I Installed Samba there ware GUI as well as internet access so that I could do all the stuff, But after Installation system asked me for restart system, I did restart and that the system didn't start. Thanx for your support I have formated that system and install the new ubuntu now.

Comment: For your information, the problem you were having was a driver issue.  If you have the problem again, you can install the proper driver through the commandline without graphics.  You mentioned Firewall internet problems.  The problem with the internet is that by default, Netmanager doesn't connect to the Wireless until a login.  That can be overridden also through the commandline without graphics.  It's a coincident that you had Graphics and Internet problems at the same time you installed Samba.  Installing Samba wasn't the culprit.

Comment: OK thanks a lot. Please refer any link or suggestion for the internet prob I got, that How to switch internet interface default to usb0 so that I can handle if I get problems like this. Thanks again.